# How to run a method after one bean but before another bean in Spring?

Tags: java, spring, javabeans

How to run a method which depends on some bean before another bean?
I have two beans. `SecondBean` depends on `FirstBean`. Also, before `SecondBean` is created I have to perform some initialization logic which should be performed with `FirstBean` and some other beans.
I would imagine something like this (it doesn't work because initialization is not a Bean):

```
@Autowired
public void initialization(FirstBean firstBean, SomeTotalyOtherBean otherBean){
    firstBean.doSomething(otherBean);
}

@Bean
@DependsOn("initialization")
public SecondBean secondBean(FirstBean firstBean) {
    return new SecondBean(firstBean);
}

@Bean
public FirstBean firstBean() {
    return new FirstBean();
}
```

I know that I could just move all initialization process into `firstBean` method but in my case it doesn't seem right because this process isn't connected with `firstBean` creation. I could also move the initialization process into `secondBean` method but it also doesn't fit there because this logic isn't connected with `secondBean` creation. It is just a logic which in only this scenario has to be performed between those beans creation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Merge firstBean() and initialization(...) such that firstBean() returns the initialized bean.

Imo it's a better design to only publish a component once it is ready to be used as a dependency / initialized.

Edit: could the initialization happen in FirstBean's constructor?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds as easy as/one possible approach:

```
/*@Autowired
public void initialization(FirstBean firstBean, SomeTotalyOtherBean otherBean){
    firstBean.doSomething(otherBean);
}*/

@Bean
@Autowired //! 
//@DependsOn("initialization")
public SecondBean secondBean(FirstBean firstBean) {
    return new SecondBean(firstBean);
}

@Autowired //! SomeTotalyOtherBean should be "visible" to this context...
@Bean
public FirstBean firstBean(SomeTotalyOtherBean other) {
    FirstBean chill = new FirstBean();//
    chill.doSomething(other);
    return chill;
}
```